# Getting sealers in POA

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, poa

how to get sealers in Proof of authority network through solidity contract, like inside a contract ?

Comment: Which client are you using (geth, parity)? I'm not aware of this being possible with geth but I believe it's possible with parity

Comment: i'm using geth.Yeah even i didn't find anything online for this.